# PC won't boot from anything but old hard drive

Tags: windows-10, boot, hp-pavilion

Machine is an HP Pavilion (circa 2014), originally with Win8; now Win10. The hard drive is failing, so I installed a new drive and installed a fresh version of Windows on it. The computer is running fine from the new hard drive; however, it will not boot if I remove the original hard drive (both are installed right now). I get an error that no boot drives are available.

I have disabled secure boot in the BIOS. msinfo confirms this. The new drive uses GPT just like the old drive. I think I've played with just about every setting I can find in the BIOS, and nothing seems to make a difference.

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like the boot folder on the first drive is still being utilized.  Disconnect old drive, boot to WinRE or boot to a Windows install USB/ISO (Shift + F10 to open terminal in setup), and issue: `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootrec /fixboot`, and finally, `bootrec /rebuildbcd`.  It's okay if the last command doesn't find a windows installation... once it finishes, close the command prompt to reboot if booted to WinRE, or cancel the Setup installation if booted to an install USB/ISO.

Comment: I should have mentioned: I literally cannot boot with ANYTHING but the original hard drive. It will not boot from USB or DVD. I've tried booting from a USB I made using Windows Media Creation tool, and from a recovery USB created within Windows. Neither is ever recognized. I also burned a DVD using Windows Media Creation; it also would not boot from that.

Comment: Remove the old hard drive and reinstall W10 on the new drive, once install is done you can connect the old drive back and both should boot.

Comment: @MikeScannell Have you tried turning off/on legacy MBR boot in the UEFI Firmware (unless yours is still BIOS, but motherboards circa 2014 should have UEFI)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if new disk has all necessary partitions for booting - EFI System partition(ESP) and Microsoft Reserved partition(some guys say there is no need for it, but stick to classic Microsoft rules)
Then fix boot files  on new disk with bcdboot command.
EFI firmware should give you possibility to order  which disk is first, set new disk as first - on UEFI you set which  boot application comes first and which second.